# Get products from different category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I face a problem with product filters, I want to show products from different categories by URL. For example if URL is `mydomain.com/product-category/mobile,tablet,ipad/` or `mydomain.com/product-category/mobile+tablet+ipad/` it shows product from all three category of mobile tablet and iPad. but in fact, it only works in one category with this this URL:
`mydomain.com/product-category/mobile/`

`mydomain.com/product-category/tablet/`

`mydomain.com/product-category/ipad/`

Is there any way to get products from different categories by URL use `,`as a separator?

Comment: There is no such default feature in WooCommerce. You must make a change in the main query loop and figure it out using `pre_get_posts` hook. Also, the better approach here would be to use query parameters `/product-category/?cats=mobile,tablet,ipad` instead of enforcing on the URL path which might mess up the main query loop and show unexpected results.

Comment: I would use, ```custom query``` and/or ```pre_get_posts```. Also I would use ```&``` instead of ```,``` or ```+```. So it'd be ```mobile&tablet&ipad```.

Comment: @RahilWazir I get `404 page` in using this structure.

Comment: @Ruvee thanks, In sing `,` It doesn't affect the result and I see all product, in case of `+`, it works only for two filters and the third category I get `no result and in case of using `&` I get `404 page`

Comment: I just tested ```,``` on my own woocommerce shop, and it works seamelesly fine. One thing that I noticed was ```/product-category/``` and ```/product-tag/```. So i'd say, make sure you're writing categories and tags in the right url.